# Total variation implementation in numpy for a piecewise linear function

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to use [total variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation) in Python, but I wasn't able to find an existing implementation.

Assuming that I have an array with a finite number of elements, is the implementation with NumPy simply as:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([...], dtype=float)
tv = np.sum(np.abs(np.diff(a)))
```

My main doubt is how to compute the supremum of `tv` across all partitions, and if just the sum of the absolute difference might suffice for a finite array of floats.

**Edit**: My input array represents a piecewise linear function, therefore the supremum over the full set of partitions is indeed the sum of absolute differences between contiguous points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

I imagine you're confused by the mathy definition on the [Wikipedia page for total variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#Definitions). Have a look at the more practical definition on the [Wikipedia page for total variation denoising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_denoising#1D_signal_series) instead.

For an actual code (even Python) implementation, see e.g. [Tensorflow's `total_variation()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.6.0/tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops_impl.py#L3213-L3282), though this is for one or more (2D, color) images, so the TV is computed for both rows and columns, and then added together.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes, indeed, I found the total variation denoising page that indicated the simplified version - that, since my array is finite and represents a piecewise linear function, is suitable for my case. I will also look at the Tensorflow's implementation, but since for this specific case my code is just one line I will use this implementation (unless there are edge cases that I'm missing atm).